# Is there a way to get all leadgen_forms in facebook api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a function that returns forms, I need to get all the forms, the problem is that this function returns 25 forms, since the limit is set to 25 by default, is it possible to get all the forms at once using the library without using requests to cycle through all the pages?

```
def get_leadgen_forms(page_id):
        try:
            all_forms = []
            page = Page(page_id)
            response = page.api_get(fields=["leadgen_forms"])
            all_forms.extend(response['leadgen_forms']['data'])
            return all_forms
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
```

I wouldn't want to do it this way(or something like that):

```
        for i in range(3):
            if response['leadgen_forms']['paging']['next']:
                next_page_url = response['leadgen_forms']['paging']['next']
                response = requests.get(next_page_url).json()
                all_forms.extend(response['data'])
                print(response, flush=True)
```

Found a similar(kind of) implementation in PHP:

```
$pagesEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
        foreach ($pagesEdge->asArray() as $ad) {
            $result[] = $ad;
            $this->AddToDb(
                $ad['id'],
                $ad['name']
            );
        }
        return $result;
```

Comment: You may try the `limit` query parameter to specify a number greater than 25 if that works for you. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/results/#paging

Comment: I have tried already hardcode like that, but for some reason it doesn't work.

params = {
                "fields": "leadgen_forms",
                "limit" : 9999,
            }
            response = page.api_get(params=params)

Comment: You can not go to whatever high limit you like though, different API endpoints have different maximum limit values they allow. So as your amount of data grows, likely sooner or later you _will_ have to use pagination anyway.

Comment: with limit = 1 also doesn't work, I mean limit doesn't woks because I can't get even 1 form, always 25.